# Smoke and fire quick effect offset from emission object

Tags: smoke-simulation

I am using blender 3.5, and I am a beginner.

When I apply a *Quick Effect* > *Fire and Smoke* on any mesh object, the effect shows offset from the emission object:

[image: offset illustration]

I tried to resize and move the outer box (I think it is called domain) so that the effect also moves and resize with it, but it did not work.

Comment: because my answer didn't help, i suggest that you use [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) to share your file.  I tried this in 3.5.1 with no problem.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you must have run the simulation which then caches the results.  Then afterwards you adjusted the location (moved) either the domain object or the emission (plane) object.

The caching of the simulation can be a bit sticky -- you need to clear this cache. Select the domain object and make a minor change to any property value (and then you can change it back) -- like one of the border collisions. That should clear the cache for the next replay.

Comment: I would also advise checking that rotations and scale are applied (see Ctrl A > Apply Rotation/Scale). Probably not the issue here, but can be, and also cause other issues.

Comment: I reinstalled blender and opened it and applied the quick effect of smoke without editing or doing anything before to the cube object still it shows a separate object with the effect and not on the the main object. Blender is a hit and miss type of software.

Comment: @How2Do  Maybe it is a bug in blender 3.5. There is no relation between the effect in the domain and the flow object. Even if i delete the flow object or resize it or move it out of the domain there is no effect on the fire and smoke inside the domain.